# Split and word count in go

Tags: strings, go

Could it be written better?

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go-tour/wc"
    "fmt"
)

func WordCount(s string) map[string]int {
    dict := make(map[string]int)

    splited := Split(s)
    for _, string := range splited {
        _, present := dict[string]
        if present {
            dict[string]++  
        } else {
            dict[string] = 1
        }
    }
    return dict
}

func Split(s string) []string{
    arraySize := 1
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == ' ' {
            arraySize++
        }
    }
    array := make([]string, arraySize)

    currentStrInd := 0
    currentStr := ""
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == ' ' {
            array[currentStrInd] = currentStr
            currentStrInd++
            currentStr = ""
        } else {
            currentStr += string(s[i])
        }
    }
    array[arraySize - 1] = currentStr
    return array;
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Split("I am learning Go!"))
    wc.Test(WordCount)
}
```

Comment: "for _, string := range splited {"
Are you using "string" as a variable Name?

Comment: oh, my bad ;..(

Answer (score 2):

For simply counting word occurrencies, yes:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func get_words_from(text string) []string{
    words:= regexp.MustCompile("\\w+")
    return words.FindAllString(text, -1)
}

func count_words (words []string) map[string]int{
    word_counts := make(map[string]int)
    for _, word :=range words{
        word_counts[word]++
    }
    return word_counts;
}

func console_out (word_counts map[string]int){
    for word, word_count :=range word_counts{
        fmt.Printf("%v %v\n",word, word_count)
    }
}

func main() {
    text := "I am learning Go! Go is a nice language to learn."
    console_out(count_words(get_words_from(text)))
}
```

Supposing, splitting by \w+ gives in most cases, what you want.

Another solution would be `(\\b[^\\s]+\\b)`. Depends on your demands.

[Go play with it!](http://play.golang.org/p/r_PFmGmGQN)

Comment: Have you considered the same word with different cases: say "Book", "book", "BOOK" should be treated as one word. Maybe convert all words to lower case before getting their counts is  a good idea.

Comment: Dependend on the result you want - this would be an improvement :]

Comment: Instead of regexp you can use strings.FieldsFunc, example https://play.golang.org/p/GrlgFyZAXB

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/go-tour/wc"
    "strings"
)

// WordCount returns a map of the counts of each “word” in the string s.
func WordCount(s string) map[string]int {
    words := strings.Fields(s)
    counts := make(map[string]int, len(words))
    for _, word := range words {
        counts[word]++
    }
    return counts
}

func main() {
    wc.Test(WordCount)
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers do not constitute a review. Please explain how your changes improve the original code.